# background color on lines of paragraph seperately - Css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add background color on lines of title, But I can't make it perfect as my client needs me to do. **My client needs this exact same:**
[image]
**And in responsive mode it should look like:**
[image]
And what i did is this I add `background-color` to text, but it's not perfect.
[image]
[image]
background color is spreading from top and bottom, tried a lot but can't figure it out.
**Here is my code:**

```css
.sectionTitle {
    font-size: 58px;
    font-size: 3.0526315789rem;
    line-height: 56px;
    line-height: .9655172414;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #233e57;
    text-align: center;
}
.sectionTitle span {
    background-color: #ffe2b3;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sectionTitle"><span>What students are Saying?</span></h1>
```

Pleas help me to solve this.

Comment: line height set 1px

Comment: @vadivela didn't work, I did this a lot

Comment: can you set text-shadow: #FC0 1px 0 10px;

Comment: U can try background image for background color

Comment: brother text-shadow is a different thing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need images, a simple gradient can do it and you will have better control over the color, size and everything

```css
.sectionTitle {
    font-size: 58px;
    font-size: 3.0526315789rem;
    line-height: 56px;
    line-height: .9655172414;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #233e57;
    text-align: center;
}
.sectionTitle span {
    background: 
      linear-gradient(#ffe2b3,#ffe2b3) 
      center/
      100% 60%  /* adjust this to control the size*/
      no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sectionTitle"><span>What students are Saying?</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help you.

```css
.sectionTitle {
  font-size: 58px;
  font-size: 3.0526315789rem;
  line-height: 56px;
  line-height: .9655172414;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #233e57;
  text-align: center;
}

.sectionTitle span {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 0.2;
  padding: 0;
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/QFNPT8G/bg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position-x: 0%;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 30px 40px;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sectionTitle"><span>What students are Saying?</span></h1>
```